# How can I solve the error "Detected applied migration not resolved locally". I use a database migration job in jenkins where flyway is involved

Tags: mysql, jenkins, scripting, database-migration, flyway

In jenkins I get the following error when I invoke flyway
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPZ1s.png)

So the error says that the script "202011020927" cannot be found.
Flyway looks at my jenkins workspace for the migration scripts.
My Flyway config looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBIbB.png)

My workspace in jenkins looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs3Wo.png)

The script that flyway is looking for is located in the versioned folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X33BP.png)

So the script is there and the path that flyway.conf is pointing to is configured correctly.
I just don't get it why I get the Detected applied migration not resolved locally error.

Or maybe I do not understand the error correctly?
Please let me know if the details are OK or if I need to supply some more info.

thanks!

I tried to adjust the flyway.conf file.
Added the flyway.outOfOrder=true rule but that didn't helped.
I still get the same error.

I used flyway.ignoreMissingMigrations, then my script is progressing but I don't think this is the right way to go.

And I checked if everything was pointing to the right dir.